# componentwise eigenvector perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector, perturbation

Does the sin-theta theorem imply a **componentwise** nonasymptotic bound for eigenvectors? Assume, for the purpose of this question, that the eigenvalues concerned are simple.

If this is trivial, I apologize in advance. I have just landed on eigenspace perturbation planet.

Comment: What is sintheta ? 

Comment: @Felix: Even though this perturbation result that you mention is standard in some contexts, it does not hurt to provide an explicit link or theorem, otherwise the question feels rather incomplete.

Comment: I mean something like this: http://books.google.ie/books?id=F4hRy1F1M6QC&q=kahan#v=snippet&q=kahan&f=false